# creating a Rosjava Service Client and Server end in failure

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, services, server, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I tried to create a rosjava service following the instruction listed in: http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava_build_tools/Tutorials/indigo/UsingServices

Sadly I end up with following error at the moment of catkin_make.

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':client_server:compileClasspath'.>
Could not find any matches for org.ros.rosjava_messages:rosjava_custom_srv:[0.1, 0.2) as no versions of org.ros.rosjava_messages:rosjava_custom_srv are available.
```

Path to subproject: ~/catkin_ws_rosjava/src/pkg_test_srv/client_server

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 -

ROS: kinetic

I followed all steps, but as you can see, I changed the package and project name.

There are also some passages in the descriptions, that were not clear enough:

1. Finally in the rosjava_tutorial_custom_services, delete the src and create a new sub-directory with two java files, the Client.java and the Server.java inside of the rosjava_tutorial_services folder

!! There is no directory or file called "rosjava_tutorial_custom_services" at that point.

2. Name differences between:

tutorial_custom_srv

rosjava_custom_srv

rosjava_tutorial_custom_services

I will really appreciate some help here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313800/creating-a-rosjava-service-client-and-server-end-in-failure/) by [yaced](https://answers.ros.org/users/39341/yaced/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-01-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2019-01-30**:
Does step 1 work for you? In `<ws_root>/devel/share/maven` you should see a folder with the artifacts of the custom generated service. The rest is a basic client / server to make use of that message, also covered   in https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core/tree/kinetic/rosjava_tutorial_services.

**Comment by [yaced](https://answers.ros.org/users/39341/yaced/) on 2019-01-30**:
Step 1 worked, yes. I was also able to resolve my problem also. It is precisely linked with the maven folder that you quoted. I had to actualize my path $ROS_MAVEN_DEPLOY_REPOSITORY, because compiling my second rosjava WS saved maven dep in my first rosjava WS. Actualizing the source wasn't enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using multiple stand-alone rosjava WS, then you should consider pointing $ROS_MAVEN_DEPLOY_REPOSITORY  to a common sourced WS or to actualize it for each rosjava WS.

---

Originally posted by [yaced](https://answers.ros.org/users/39341/yaced/) with karma: 26 on 2019-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2019-01-30**:
Cool, thanks for sharing your solution!
Maybe the tutorial needs some tweaking / better explanations. The main point is actually to show how to use `genjava` for custom messages, which is actually a basic ROS task, but many java devs are not familiar with it.